# Flask-ask AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'

Tags: python, flask, python-cryptography, flask-ask

I'm using flask-ask in virtual environment with Ngrok. I keep getting 500 Internal server errors

I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\laptop\Envs\alexa\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
    method = _lib.X509V3_EXT_get(self._extension)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
```

I've tried downgrading to older versions of cryptography but they won't install. I get this error.

```
  _openssl.c
    build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_openssl.c(501): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/aes.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I've installed visual studio with C++ thinking it was something to do with  compiling but that hasn't worked either.

I've also updated setuptools, install OpenSSL and nothing seems to work. My theory is that Flask-Ask is no longer compatible with the version of cryptography, but older versions of cryptography are no long installable because of compiling issues.

Comment: @brendan-odonnell how did you fixed it?

Comment: @DavidNogueira  I'll go ahead and confess it wasn't a pretty fix. I just went into the source code, found the function that was asking for X509V3 and deleted it. It basically did the job and it worked fine once is stopped asking for that attribute.